# How to change innerHTML of blockquote to plaintext with > at the start of every new line?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to convert the `innerHTML` component of all `blockquote` elements inside a parent container element with a `>` at the start of every line inside the said `blockquote` element such that HTML like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbfkL.png

would look like this after being processed by the function:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZfww.png

Something I've tried (amateurishly) but doesn't produce the right results:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("blockquote");

doit(nodes[0]);

function doit(x) {
  x.outerHTML = x.outerHTML.replace(/(<[\/]?blockquote[^>]*>)/g, "&gt;");
}
```

Here is the raw HTML inside the concerned parent container:

```
<br><br>On Wed, Mar 31, 2019 at 01:50 AM Some Name &lt;someone@something.com&gt; wrote:<br><blockquote style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0.8ex;border-left:1px solid rgb(204,204,204);padding-left:1ex">
<div>A hello to you!&nbsp;</div><br>
<div><div>On Wed, Mar 31, 2019 at 1:29 AM Some User &lt;<a href="mailto:someuser@something.com">someuser@soemthing.com</a>&gt; wrote:</div><blockquote style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0.8ex;border-left:1px solid rgb(204,204,204);padding-left:1ex"><div style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif">
<p>Hello,</p>
<p>How is it going?</p>

</div>
</blockquote></div>

</blockquote>
```